# При наследовании класс родителя возвращает 0

Tags: c#, наследование

При вызову Soldier метод Soldier.FindQ() возвращает произведние weight и hight, как и нужно. Но при вызове SoldierNew (потомок) Soldier.FindQ() всегда возвращает 0, из-за чего SoldierNew.FindQ() считает непраивльно. Не понимаю в чем ошибка?!

```
public class Soldier
{
    private string surname;
    private int height;
    private int weigth;
    protected double q;

    public Soldier(string surname, int height, int weigth)
    {
        this.surname = surname;
        this.height = height;
        this.weigth = weigth;
        q = FindQ();
    }

    public virtual double FindQ()
    {
        return height * weigth;
    }

    public String PrintInfo()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(' ' + surname + '\n' + 
            "Рост - " + height + '\n' + 
            "Вес - " + weigth + '\n' + 
            "Q - " + FindQ() + '\n');
        return sb.ToString();
    }
public class SoldierNew : Soldier
{
    private Education p;
    public SoldierNew(string surname, int height, int weigth, Education p) : base(surname, height, 
weigth)
    {
        this.p = p;
    }

    public override double FindQ()
    {
        if (p.Equals(Education.higher))
            return 2 * q;
        if (p.Equals(Education.primary))
            return 0.5 * q;
        return q;
    }
}
```

Comment: ну все верно, вы же q не дали никакого начального значения. Вы расчитываете значение переменной используя эту же переменную? Это как так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы создаёте объект SoldierNew то вы входите в конструктор базового класса и в нём начинаете считать q. Только расчёт идёт вызывая FindQ из наследника, а не из базового класса.

Но там получается вот какой момент: чтобы посчитать q вам надо знать q, а его нет.

По логике вероятно вы ожидаете что-то типа:

```
public override double FindQ()
{
    q = base.FindQ();

    if (p.Equals(Education.higher))
        return 2 * q;
    if (p.Equals(Education.primary))
        return 0.5 * q;
    return q;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Update: Если я правильно понял, то  @tym32167 предлагает более правильный вариант:

```
public override double FindQ()
{
    var baseQ = base.FindQ();
    
    if (p.Equals(Education.higher))
        return 2 * baseQ;
        
    if (p.Equals(Education.primary))
        return 0.5 * baseQ;
    
    return baseQ;
}
```

Comment: хз что там по логике, но такие функции должны быть идемпотентными, иначе вызывая q=findq() много раз можно уйти в 0 или в бесконечность.

Comment: @tym32167 Вроде всё понял, но ничего не понял. Сейчас разультат остаётся тот же, что и при повторном вызове. Что не так?

Comment: Функция, которая рассчитывает q по идее не должна использовать q, чтобы рассчитать q :) В вашем конкретно примере использование поля q в принципе бессмысленное. Мало того, ваша функция getXXX имеет сайд эффект - изменение поля класса, что не должно происходить (почитайе про [CQS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation)). По большому счету, в функции в вашей редакции мне не нравится откровенно всё, имхо она стала еще хуже, чем была.

Comment: замените использование внутреннего поля `q = base.FindQ();` на использование переменной `var baseQ = base.FindQ();` и обновите остальной код на использование этой переменной и функция заиграет новыми красками :)

Comment: да, действительно заработало, как предложил А К, и я думаю, это то что хотел от нас преподаватель. Спасибо большое!

Comment: @tym32167 Поправил (см. обновление ответа), сравнил с предыдущим вариантом, но всё равно не могу понять, чем стало лучше.

Comment: вы избавились от побочного эффекта (см Clean Code chapter 3). Теперь кто бы не использовал поле q, его логика не будет поломана из за вашей функции. Теперь ваша функция делает только то, что написано в её названии. Если вы не видите разницу, я вам серьезно советую почитать Clean Code (разделы про именование функции, ответсвенность функции, побочные эффекты функции) и о вреде побочных эффектов.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь я тоже поняла, почему так правильно и почему до этого не работало )))

Comment: @tym32167 А, теперь понял. Теперь функция стала чистой: перестала модифицировать q.

Comment: Нет, функция чистой не стала. Чистая функция зависит только от входящих параметров. Ваша функция зависит от функции в базовом классе + от состояния поля `p`. Пример чистой функции `int sum(x, y) => x+y;`. Ваша функция стала лучше только тем, что избавилась от побочного эффекта.

Comment: @tym32167 Угу, я как раз и написал сначала "стала чистой", но потом добавил, что именно "перестала модифицировать q", двинулась в направлении "большей чистоты".